# Using intents to send strings to new activitys

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm new to android and am trying to learn how to use intents to start new activity's and send strings to them. Can someone please tell me why this wont work:

```
package com.example.experimentingwithactivities;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView View;
    String String1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void onButton1Click (View v) {
        String morestuff  = "Something";

        Intent i = new Intent(this, other_activity.class);
        i.putExtra("stuff", morestuff);
        startActivity(i); 
    }

}
```

and this is the second activity

```
package com.example.experimentingwithactivities;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class other_activity extends Activity{
    TextView something;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seccond_activity);

        something = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String morestuff = intent.getStringExtra("stuff");

        something.setText(morestuff);
    }
}
```

whenever I run this, it stops unexpectedly. any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Post the stacktrace from the crash

Comment: You need to declare all your activities in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: I think I forgot to add the seccond activity to the AdroidManisfest. I'm doing that now. If it crashes again I'll post the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this first:

```
    TextView something;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.seccond_activity);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String morestuff = intent.getStringExtra("stuff");

        //comment this out if it does not crash
        //something = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.textView1);
        //something.setText(morestuff);
}
```

If it crashes it means `textView1` does not belong to `seccond_activity.xml` rename it to `someting_textview1`.

Comment: From my experience with android this always been the case

Comment: "Always"? Hmmm...likely but from my experience it hasn't been always, just saying

Comment: Well you should post your answer if you have a better one, we are all trying to help you know

Comment: Easy...there is no real answer without logcat. I'm just trying to help keep SO clean. But you can't say this is *always* the problem